# Clean URLS work with http, but not with https

Tags: uri

When I visit **?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls** via HTTP I am able to enable clean URLs and they work fine.

However, when I visit the same path via HTTPS I am not able to enable clean URLs and get this error:

[image]

Here is my apache conf file for http:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>

    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /media/www_drive/drupal7

  <Directory /media/www_drive/drupal7>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my apache conf file for https

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/cgps/star.cgps.org.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/cgps/np_cgps.key
    ServerAdmin webmaster@cgps.org
    DocumentRoot /media/www_drive/drupal7
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/cgps/RapidSSL.crt

    <Directory /media/www_drive/drupal7>
      Require all granted
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Shouldn't this config use the same `.htacess` file in the drupal root for both HTTP and HTTPS? What could cause clean URLs to fail to pass the check via HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below with changing in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off   
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```